# Not deleting message when banning members

Tags: discord.js

This is my ban code:

```js
                reason: reason || 'No reason provided',
                deleteMessageDays: time || 0,
            })
```

the problem is that when I inputted time, it would not delete messages. Time is a number. If your wondering, here is my code for time:

```
     let time = Number(args.reverse()[0].split('').reverse().slice(1).join(''))
        if (time) {
            if (args.length === 1) {
                reason = "No reason provided."
            } 

            time = args[0].split('').reverse()

            if (time[0] === 's') {
                time = Number(time.slice(1).reverse().join(''))
            } else if (time[0] === 'm') {
                time = 60 * Number(time.slice(1).reverse().join(''))
            } else if (time[0] === 'h') {
                time = 60 * 60 * Number(time.slice(1).reverse().join(''))
            } else if (time[0] === 'd') {
                time = 60 * 60 * 24 * Number(time.slice(1).reverse().join(''))
            }else {
                reason = args.slice(1).reverse().slice(1).join(' ')
            }

            if (time > 604800) {
                time = 604800
            }

            time = time / 86400
        } else {
            reason = args.slice(1).join()
        }
```

There is no errors at all, and it would ban the user, it's just that it just wont delete messages when inputted time.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `deleteMessageSeconds` and calculate the time in seconds as it says in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/BanOptions)

Comment: I tried too, but it also doesn't work. I was originally using deleteMessageSeconds, which does not work. I asked someone and they told me to use deleteMessageDays, but sadly it also doesn't work.